# extend the functionality of datepicker (ui bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to extend the functionality of ui bootstrap for the datepicker. I wanted to use a draggable directive that I have already made for other elements, so I can drag the days. (The final functionality will beassigning that date to certain tasks). What would be ideal for me is not to modify the ui bootstrap libraries. I have tried to insert the directive in the final html of the datepicker and then use the compile, but I can't make it work.

Can anybody help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you please share some code? Html and any JS attempts

Comment: It's actually should be not very difficult, since you already have directives for draggability. Just customize datepicker templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more powerful datepicker you can use the [Dan Grossman's DateRangePicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker).

[image]

There is also a good implementation for angular that you can use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-daterangepicker

Simply inject the library in your angular module.

```
App = angular.module('app', ['daterangepicker']);
```

Then declare a model in your controller.

```
exampleApp.controller('TestCtrl', function () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.datePicker.date = {
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null
  };
}
```

Finally use the directive in your views.

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl">
  <input date-range-picker class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="ctrl.datePicker.date" />
</div>
```